# Set Dynamic Approvers in Approval Workflow

Tags: list, workflow

I need to implement an approval workflow on a list. Whenever a form is submitted, several Managers need to approve it. The selection of managers is based on a multiple selection box where users select several categories. Each category has its own category Manager so if categories were selected, the workflow should send the form to each Manager.

Im looking for a general idea how to implement that, not a detailed solution.

My thought was to a calculated field where all manager names are stored based on the user selection. The workflow sends the form to the Managers based on this calculated field.

Is there a better way, or is this even possible to implement?